# Trying to get property of non-object code igniter while displaying TEXT type column value

Tags: codeigniter

How to read review_text column value using code igniter,

In this line code igniter gives me below error

```
<p class="excerpt" align="justify"><?=$review->REVIEW_TEXT;?></p>
```

Gives me Error while displaying on webpage

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/reviewpage.php

Line Number: 83
```

This my table

```
CREATE TABLE  `techreview`.`trn_reviews` (
  `review_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `review_url` varchar(200) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `review_text` text collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `review_dt` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`review_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

This is my model method which

```
function getReviewDetails($url){    
    $this->db->select('REVIEW_URL,REVIEW_TEXT');
    $whereCondition = $array = array('REVIEW_URL' =>$url);       
    $this->db->where($whereCondition); 
    $query = $this->db->get("trn_reviews");
    return $query->result();            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're doing something like this?

```
<?php
  $review = $this->my_model->getReviewDetails("url_text_here");
?>
<p class="excerpt" align="justify"><?=$review->REVIEW_TEXT;?></p>
```

Shouldn't you loop through the result set?

```
<?php
  $review = $this->my_model->getReviewDetails("url_text_here");
  foreach($review as $row) {
?>
<p class="excerpt" align="justify"><?=$row->review_text;?></p>
<?php
  }
?>
```

If your query will only return 1 row, then you can use the `$query->row()` method:

```
// in your model
function getReviewDetails($url){    
    $this->db->select('REVIEW_URL,REVIEW_TEXT');
    $whereCondition = $array = array('REVIEW_URL' =>$url);       
    $this->db->where($whereCondition); 
    $query = $this->db->get("trn_reviews");
    return $query->row();          
}

// in your view
<?php
  $review = $this->my_model->getReviewDetails("url_text_here");
?>
<p class="excerpt" align="justify"><?=$review->review_text;?></p>
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html